# python array error

Tags: python, io, text-files, vpython

hello   I am trying to load coordinates for plotting from a text file and I keep getting an error I don't understand. The coordinates look like this in the file `(0.1, 0.0, 0.0),
(0.613125, 0.52202, 0.19919)` Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
from visual import *

with open ('/Desktop/Coordlist2.txt','r') as open_file:

    rightFace = curve(pos=[(1,-1,-1), (1,-1,1), (1,-1,-1),(1,1,-1),(1,1,-1),(1,1,1),(1,1,1),(1,-1,1)], radius=0.01, color=color.cyan)
    backFace = curve(pos=[(1,-1,-1), (-1,-1,-1), (-1,-1,-1),(-1,1,-1),(-1,1,-1),(1,1,-1)], radius=0.01, color=color.cyan)
    leftFace = curve(pos=[(-1,-1,-1), (-1,-1,1), (-1,-1,1),(-1,1,1),(-1,1,1),(-1,1,-1)], radius=0.01, color=color.cyan)
    frontFace = curve(pos=[(-1,-1,1), (1,-1,1), (1,1,1),(-1,1,1)], radius=0.01, color=color.cyan)

    for line in open_file.readlines():
        coords = line
        points(pos=[coords], size=1, color=color.yellow)
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Graphs.py", line 15, in <module>
    points(pos=[coords], size=1, color=color.yellow)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vis/primitives.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.process_init_args_from_keyword_dictionary( keywords )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vis/primitives.py", line 212, in process_init_args_from_keyword_dictionary
    setattr(self, key, value)
ValueError: Object cannot be converted to array.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How they look in the file is irrelevant; they're read as strings. You'll need to parse the lines before they can be used; try [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
for line in open_file.readlines():
    coords = line
```

When you read a line from a file, you always get a string. You then have to process that string to produce whatever data structure you need. So if you have a line that looks like this (for example)

```
l = '(5, 6, 7)'
```

you have to explicitly break it up and create a tuple from it:

```
l_tuple = tuple(int(n) for n in l.strip('()').split(','))
```

Also, as agf reminded me, you should probably just do `for line in open_file`; `open_file.readlines` creates a copy of the file in memory, while `for line in open_file` just iterates over the lines individually, without copying the entire file into memory.

Just to be as complete as possible, to convert a string that looks like this:

```
s = '(0.1, 0.0, 0.0), (0.613125, 0.52202, 0.19919)'
```

You can do this:

```
>>> numbers = tuple(float(n.strip('( )')) for n in s.split(','))
>>> t1, t2 = numbers[:3], numbers[3:]
```

This works as long as there are always two tuples of 3 per line.

agf's solution in his comment works too, but it's a bit more brittle, since the tuples *must* be separated by `'), ('` exactly. To tell the truth, Ignacio's solution is really the best. :)

Comment: It should also be `for line in open_file:`

Comment: This is what it outputs: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/WordGraphs.py", line 11, in <module>
    l_tuple = tuple(int(n) for n in line.strip('()').split(','))
  File "/Users/Desktop/WordGraphs.py", line 11, in <genexpr>
    l_tuple = tuple(int(n) for n in line.strip('()').split(','))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.1'

Comment: @English Grad, you have to use `float` instead of `int` then. Generally, you should really give more information about what kind of data you're processing; otherwise our answers are at best guesses.

Comment: Sorry about that, I put the file contents in the post I thought that was enough. Thanks for the help.

Comment: senderle, it is still not working. it returns this error: l_tuple = tuple(float(n) for n in l.strip('()').split(','))
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0.0). I really have no idea what I am doing I am sorry

Comment: Ah, I see you did put information about the file at the top of your question. Sorry. Well you might try [Ignacio's method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807300/python-array-error/6807493#6807493). I'm a bit mystified by "invalid literal for float(): 0.0".

Comment: @English it's _two tuples_ on one line, so you need `coords = tuple(tuple(float(t) for t in a.split(', ')) for a in line.strip('()').split('), ('))`

Comment: @English, ah, I understand now. The invalid literal is the extra `)` char at the end of 0.0. I'll edit my answer again.